# Check if successive Elements are different (less than)

Tags: java, arraylist, element

I am wondering if there is a way to compare successive elements in an arrayList. I have 
this

```
for (int j=0; j< Index.size(); j++) {
   if(Index.get(j) < Index.get(j -1) {  
       System.out.println("Total number of shapes is " + sizer);
   } 
}
```

Problem is my code crashes when it gets to this point and I am not sure how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: start at j = 1. "crashes" means IndexOutofBoundException -1

Comment: It crashes when j = 0, get(-1) will be out of bound and also sizer is undefined. Can you give more detail about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your index starts at 0 and you are trying to get the -1th element instead try initializing `j` to 1

Answer (score 1):

Change the start of the for loop:

```
for (int j=1; j< Index.size(); j++) {
   if(Index.get(j) < Index.get(j -1) {  
       System.out.println("Total number of shapes is " + sizer);
   } 
}
```